# How does Docker image clean up works on kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have k8s cluster with three workers and when I explicitly creates the pod, corresponding docker images get downloaded to worker. When I explicitly deletes the pods corresponding docker images are still present on worker nodes. Is this expected case?

Answer (score 7):

> Is this expected case?

Possibly, considering the [Kubernetes Garbage collection policy for images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/):

> Kubernetes manages lifecycle of all images through `imageManager`, with the cooperation of `cadvisor`.
>
> The policy for garbage collecting images takes two factors into consideration: `HighThresholdPercent` and `LowThresholdPercent`.
> Disk usage above the high threshold will trigger garbage collection.
> The garbage collection will delete least recently used images until the low threshold has been met.